# Is this correct for pressure exerted by a liquid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, vectors, fluid-statics

[image]
$P_0$ is atmospheric pressure and
$P_1$ is height×density×gravity.

So , is the diagram correct for saying that

Total pressure in the liquid = $P_0+P_1$.
Since the direction of $P_0$ vector is downwards?

Comment: There are two common ways to measure pressure.  Absolute pressure is atmospheric pressure plus pressure due to $\rho g h$.  Gauge pressure is just pressure due to $\rho g h$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, pressure is not a vector so don't go by the directions.

Talking about pressure, it increases with an increase in height. So you write pressure at any point at depth $h$ as

$P_\text{depth} = P_0+h \rho g$

So your answer is correct